# JAXB: XmlJavaTypeAdapter with XmlElementRef (type=JAXBElement)

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, jaxb2

The question is related to JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6

From yesterday, I am tring to figure out the way to define an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` together with `XmlElementRef` on a field.

From the net, I have got several examples that shows this usage, but all of them works with element name generated from `@XmlRootElement` of the value type. 
My Problem lies in the fact that I have a reference whose type is `JAXBElement<T>`

To clarify, let me put up the scenario.

The schema (to which I do not have control) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
            targetNamespace="blah_blah"
            xmlns:tns="blah_blah" >

<element name="productContext" type="tns:ProductContext" />

<complexType name="ProductContext">
    <sequence>
        <element name="product" type="tns:Product" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" />
        <element name="owner" type="string" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Product">
    <sequence>
        <element name="item" type="tns:Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="id" type="int" use="optional" />
</complexType>

<complexType name="Item">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="string" />
        <element name="category" type="string" />
        <element name="range" type="string" />
        <element name="price" type="double" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

</schema>
```

I compiled the schema through XJC & I get following files generated -

1. package-info.java
2. ObjectFactory.java
3. ProductContext.java
4. Product.java
5. Item.java

The XML that I want to unmarshal is like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<productContext xmlns="blah_blah">
      <product id="11">
           <item>
            <name>item_0</name>
            <category>category_0</category>
            <range>range_0</range>
            <price>300</price>
          </item>
          <item>
            <name>item_1</name>
            <category>category_1</category>
            <range>range_1</range>
            <price>400</price>
          </item>
     </product>
     <owner>Vikas</owner>
</productContext>
```

I am able to unmarshal it as following Test Class :

```
package test.jaxb;

import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductContext.class);
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<ProductContext> productContext = (JAXBElement<ProductContext>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\test.xml"));

        Product product = productContext.getValue().getProduct().getValue();

        System.out.println("Product Id : " + product.getId());
        System.out.println("Item 0 : " + product.getItem().get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("Item 1 : " + product.getItem().get(1).getName());
    }
}
```

Running this will yield me :

```
Product Id : 11
Item 0 : item_0
Item 1 : item_1
```

**My Issue is as follows:**

In `ProductContext` class, 
I want to to have a `java.util.HashMap<String, Item>` inplace of `Product`

to allow lookup of Items based on Item Name (I don't want to change Product class though)

Currently `ProductContext` class has got Reference Of Product ,
rather then Product itself
(becuase of: minOccurs="0"  & nillable="true") like following -

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProductContext", propOrder = {
    "product",
    "owner"
})
public class ProductContext {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "product", namespace = "blah_blah", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<Product> product;

    ..
```

}

ObjectFactory looks like:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    ..

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link Product }
     * 
     */
    public Product createProduct() {
        return new Product();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Product }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "blah_blah", name = "product", scope = ProductContext.class)
    public JAXBElement<Product> createProductContextProduct(Product value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Product>(_ProductContextProduct_QNAME, Product.class, ProductContext.class, value);
    }
}
```

I tried to Introduce an Adapter called `ProductAdapter` like following

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProductContext", propOrder = {
    "product",
    "owner"
})
public class ProductContext {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "product", namespace = "blah_blah", type = JAXBElement.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(test.jaxb.ProductAdapter.class)
    protected HashMap<String, Item> product;

    ..
}
```

& Adapter as:

```
package test.jaxb;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ProductAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<Product>, HashMap<String, Item>> {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Item> unmarshal(JAXBElement<Product> valueType) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, Item> map = new HashMap<String, Item>();
        Product product = valueType.getValue();

        for(Item item : product.getItem()) {
            map.put(item.getName() , item);
        }

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<Product> marshal(HashMap<String, Item> boundType) throws Exception {
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
        Product product = factory.createProduct();

        for(Entry<String, Item> entry : boundType.entrySet()) {
            product.getItem().add(entry.getValue());
        }

        // return a JAXBElement of Product which is ProductContext Scoped 
        return factory.createProductContextProduct(product);
    }
}
```

I am still able to unmarshal it using Test class -

```
package test.jaxb;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductContext.class);
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<ProductContext> productContext = (JAXBElement<ProductContext>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\test.xml"));

        /*
        Product product = productContext.getValue().getProduct().getValue();

        System.out.println("Product Id : " + product.getId());
        System.out.println("Item 0 : " + product.getItem().get(0).getName());
        System.out.println("Item 1 : " + product.getItem().get(1).getName());
        */

        for(Entry<String, Item> entry : productContext.getValue().getProduct().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println( "Item name : " + entry.getKey() + " , value : " + entry.getValue().getCategory());  
        }
    }
}
```

which yields following output -

```
Item name : item_1 , value : category_1
Item name : item_0 , value : category_0
```

***However the problem is with Adapter's ValueType***

`ProductAdapter` 's value type is `JAXBElement<Product>` & not `Product`

```
ProductAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<Product>, HashMap<String, Item>>
```

What I don't like using this is:

- My Adapter is tightly coupled to only 1 JAXBElement 
  (In this case: {"blah_blah"}product with ProductContext scope)
  This adapter will not work with Other elements of same type `Product`

I tried enhancing the Adapter as -

```
public class ProductAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Product, HashMap<String, Item>>
```

But it gives issues during both Unmarshalling (no population of Map) &
Marshalling (gives exception - unable to marshal type "test.jaxb.Product" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation)

**Can somebody please guide me how do I use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` with
`@XmlElementRef(type=JAXBElement)` without Adapter returning JAXBElement as value Type ??**

Comment: I think what you demand is impossible. From JAXB/XML point of view, `ProductContext.product` can be either `Product` or `Owner`. For this cases JAXB introduces `JAXBElement` (a universal wrapper) because JAXB needs to know the element name (and `Product` is the representation of type and can have different XML element names in different incarnations).